# Multiplying Integers on a For Loop

Tags: javascript, types, type-conversion, iteration, multiplication

Beginning JavaScript learner here...

I'm working through Adrian Neumann's [Simple Programming Problems](https://adriann.github.io/programming_problems.html) and my question is about number 6 in the elementary exercises.

> Write a program that asks the user for a number `n` and gives him the possibility to choose between computing the sum and computing the product of 1,…,`n`.

```
// var myArray = []; // for testing
var mySum = 0;
var userNum = prompt("What is your number? ");
var userChoice = prompt("Would you like to add up (+) or multiply (*) all the numbers from 1 to your number? Please enter (+) or (*): ");

if (userChoice == "+") {
    for (var i = userNum; i > 0; i--) {
        mySum += +i;
    }
    console.log("Your answer is " + mySum);
} else if (userChoice == "*") {
    for (var i = userNum; i > 0; i--) {
        mySum *= +i;
        // myArray.push(i); // for testing
    }
    console.log("Your answer is " + mySum);
    // console.log(myArray); // for testing
}
```

When entering values for multiplication, the answer is always `0`. Obviously, I thought `0` was being included in the iteration, so I setup an empty array `myArray`, and pushed all the numbers to the array using `myArray.push(i);`... `0` was never included as a value in the array.

Other than some obvious form-validation considerations, can anyone tell me what I'm missing? Why is my answer always `0`?

**Note**: The `sum` section of the code seems to work brilliantly.

Please note I'm a *beginniner* to JavaScript, so if you'd like to comment, let me know WHY you changed the code the way you do, rather than simply spitting back code to me. That's a big help, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you initialize `mySum` to `0` so in every iteration of the loop you'll multiplying `i` by zero and save the result (again, zero) back into `mySum`. For multiplication you'd have to start at one.

Comment: It's the little things, eh? Very humbling experience, this is.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set `mySum` to `1` before multiplication. `0*i` = 0.